# Что за ошибка Failed: DID NOT RAISE <class 'ValueError'>

Tags: python, pytest

Есть вот такая функция:

```
@property
def p_area(self):
    return self.area

@p_area.setter
def p_area(self, value):
    print(f"Площадь фигуры '{self.name}' = {self.area + value}")
    if not isinstance(value, (int, float)):
        raise ValueError('Значение не является числом')
```

Мне нужно проверить, self.area увеличивается на заданное в value значение и если это значение- не число, выдавать ошибку.
Написал следующий тест в pytest:

```
def test_p_area(self):
    with pytest.raises(ValueError):
      my_tri = Triangle(name="Треугольник", area=5, angles=3, perimeter=9)
    my_tri.p_area()
```

По выполнению возникает вот такая ошибка  `Failed: DID NOT RAISE <class 'ValueError'>`

Comment: Ошибка буквально означает, что вы указали, что блок кода должен выбрасывать исключение (`with pytest.raises(ValueError):`), но он его не выбрасывает.

Answer (score 1):

1. В вашем сеттере нужно переставить обработку ошибки, иначе `self.area + value` упадет раньше, и ошибка будет совсем другая  `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'`

```
@p_area.setter
def p_area(self, value):
    if not isinstance(value, (int, float)):
        raise ValueError('Значение не является числом')
    print(f"Площадь фигуры '{self.name}' = {self.area + value}")
```

2. В тестах сеттер надо исполнять внутри контекс менеджера и не надо его вызывать как метод.

```
def test_p_area(self):
    with pytest.raises(ValueError):
        my_tri = Triangle(name="Треугольник", area=5, angles=3, perimeter=9)
        my_tri.p_area = '1'
```

Comment: Спасибо  большое, вопрос решен